Are Dementors found all over the world, or do they only reside in or near Britain?
According to the story, Dementors are only really active on their native island of Azkaban but are somewhat under the control of the British Ministry of Magic until Voldemort returns to full power in the Second Wizarding War. They are not known to be active or have a different permanent location elsewhere. Does that mean that they are unique to Britain, and why don't other countries have them?

That sounds like a question could make interesting fan fiction, perhaps explaining the histories or common personality types of various regions by how common dementors are in those regions.

One of the W.O.M.B.A.T. questions on J.K. Rowling's original website related to Dementors in other parts of the world.
The question was:

13. Which of the following is TRUE?
a. To become an Inferius, a person must have been murdered by Dark Magic.
b. Occlumency can guard against possession.
c. Dementors are unknown in tropical climates.
d. A curse is stronger than a hex, which is stronger than a jinx.
e. If a werewolf mates at the full moon, they will produce a cub rather than a human baby.

Since the correct answer was D (and A was partially true), it stands to reason that C must be false and that Dementors ARE known in tropical climates.
No part of the British Isles has a tropical climate, so Dementors must be able to be found outside of the UK. QED.

Little do we know, Britain would be a tropical climate if not for having all the Dementors making the weather cold and dreary.

@ShadowRanger The dementors are responsible for the weather, Crowley is responsible for the traffic disaster... just imagine how good life could be!

I'd always assumed they were from Sheffield.

Well, the UK does have Overseas Territories in tropical areas, and presumably they are under control of the British Ministry of Magic.
